# I want to go to the all the pages of yelp webiste and extract data from

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I want to go to all the pages of the yelp site but cann't
this is the code

```
# packages
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import urllib
import os
import json
import datetime
import csv

# property scraper class
class Yelp(scrapy.Spider):
    # scraper name
    name = 'home business'
    base_url = 'https://www.yelp.com/search?'
    params = {
     'find_desc': 'Home Cleaning',
     'find_loc':'North Dallas, Dallas, TX',
     #'start' : ''
     }
    page = 0
    current_page = 1
    # headers
    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36"
        
     }
    #params['start'] = page
    try:
       os.remove('abx.csv')
    except OSError:
       pass   
    # custom settings
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUEST_PER_DOMAIN': 2,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1
    }

    # general crawler
    def start_requests(self):
            url = self.base_url + urllib.parse.urlencode(self.params)
            # initial HTTP request
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url,
                headers=self.headers,
               
                callback=self.parse_listing
            )
            
    def parse_listing(self, response):
            
            lists = response.css('h4[class="css-1l5lt1i"]')
            
            for link in lists:
                link = link.css('a::attr(href)').get() 
                link =  'https://www.yelp.com/' + link            
                #print('\n\nlink:',link,'\n\n')
                yield response.follow(link, headers = self.headers, callback = self.parse_cards)
                break
                
            try:    
                
              #self.params['start'] = self.page
              try:
                  total_pages =  response.css('.text-align--center__09f24__1P1jK .css-e81eai::text').get()[5:7]
                  print(total_pages)

 
                  self.page +=10
                  self.current_page +=1
                  

              except Exception as e:
                 total_pages = 1
                 print('totl:',total_pages)
                 print('PAGE %s | %s ' % (self.current_page, total_pages)) 
                 
 
 
              if int(self.page/10) <= int(total_pages):
                self.log('\n\n %s | %s\n\n ' %(self.page/10, total_pages))
                next_page = response.url + '&start=' + str(self.page)
                yield response.follow(url = next_page, headers = self.headers, callback = self.parse_listing) 
            except:
             print('only single page',self.current_page)

           
    def parse_cards(self,response):
      print('\nok\n')   
      
# main driver
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run scraper
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(Yelp)
    process.start()
    
    #Yelp.parse_cards(Yelp, '')
```

I applied try and except method also but cann't done the job.
The main problem is in the next page with the param '&start=' if i increment the start to 10 in every time then the url become every time like this

```
'https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Home+Cleaning&find_loc=North+Dallas%2C+Dallas%2C+TX&start=10&start=20&start=30'
```

and so on i want to only the url start will increment to start=10 and after them start=20 and so on.
like this

```
'https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Home+Cleaning&find_loc=North+Dallas%2C+Dallas%2C+TX&start=20'

'https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Home+Cleaning&find_loc=North+Dallas%2C+Dallas%2C+TX&start=30'
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find the link to the next page and follow that

```py
next_page = response.css("a.next-link::attr(href)").get()
if next_page:
    yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

This is pretty similar to what is done in the [scrapy tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html), have you followed that? Was there a reason you couldn't do it this way?

In the end your entire spider can become

```py
from scrapy import Spider


class Yelp(Spider):
    # scraper name
    name = "home business"
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Home+Cleaning&find_loc=North+Dallas%2C+Dallas%2C+TX"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        for link in response.css("h4 > span > a"):
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_cards)

        next_page = response.css("a.next-link::attr(href)").get()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_cards(self, response):
        print("parse_cards", response.url)
```

I removed the `start_requests` stuff to keep it simple for this example (something you should probably try to do [when asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))